# What is the best way to insert python datetime in rethinkdb?

Tags: python, datetime, utc, rethinkdb

[RethinkDB](http://rethinkdb.com/) is a wonderfull and very handy NoSQL Database engine. I looking for the best way to insert Python datetime objects. RethinkDB strores UTC timestamps, so I found a solution to convert my datetime object in the right format.

I use this litle function to convert my datetime object in somethink RethinkDB understand :

```
import calendar
from datetime import datetime
import rethinkdb as r


def datetime_to_epoch_time(dt):
    timestamp = calendar.timegm(dt.utctimetuple())
    return r.epoch_time(timestamp)

title = u'foobar'
published_at = '2014-03-17 14:00'

# firts I convert 2014-03-17 14:00 to datetime
dt = datetime.strptime(published_at, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')

# then I store the result
r.table('stories').insert({
    'title': title,
    'published_at': datetime_to_epoch_time(dt),
}).run()
```

My current timezone is CET (GMT + 2 hours)
Is this a good solution for storing my dates in rethinkdb or a better solution exists ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I suspect that you're storing the wrong time in the database. The line `dt = datetime.strptime(meta['published_at'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')` will result in a datetime object that is timezone naive as you haven't specified the timezone anywhere. Is it in CET? Is it in UTC? Given this ambiguity, what is `dt.utctimetuple()` going to return? If you're dealing with timezones, it's best to always work with timezone aware datetime objects. For more details, have a look at [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net)

Comment: +1 for the above comment - always store your datetimes in a format the timezone information is preserved. Even if you are not working with multicountry data set daylight saving time may cause issues.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand the importance of timezone in datetime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An example with Pytz :

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

import rethinkdb as r


# Init
r.connect('localhost', 28015).repl()
if 'test' in r.db_list().run():
    r.db_drop('test').run()

r.db_create('test').run()
r.db('test').table_create('stories').run()

paris = pytz.timezone('Europe/Paris')

r.table('stories').insert({
    'title': u'Foobar',
    'published_at': paris.localize(datetime.strptime(
        '2014-03-17 14:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'
    ), is_dst=False)
}).run()

for document in r.table("stories").run():
    print(document['published_at'])
    print(type(document['published_at']))
```

Comment: For me this seems to be the best solution. I realize that I can use native datetime objects instead of converting them in timestamps and keep the right timezone. pytz looks amazing

Answer (score 1):

`dt.utctimetuple()` doesn't convert a naive `dt` to UTC timezone i.e., if `published_at` is not in UTC already then it returns the wrong result.

If `published_at` is in local timezone and therefore `dt` is in local timezone:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz # $ pip install pytz
from tzlocal import get_localzone # $ pip install tzlocal

tz = get_localzone()
aware_dt = tz.localize(dt, is_dst=None)
timestamp = (aware_dt - datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=pytz.utc)).total_seconds()
# ... r.epoch_time(timestamp)
```